# ZFS - zfs destroy snapshot during zfs send incremental

Tags: zfs, snapshot

How does zfs handle destroying snapshots during an incremental send?

Example:

2 servers using ZFS:

**zfshost1**

```
[root@zfshost1~]# zfs list -t snapshot
NAME
zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-1
zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-2
zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-3
zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-4
```

**zfshost2**

```
[root@zfshost2~]# zfs list -t snapshot
NAME
zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-1
```

Now incrementally send snapshot-2 to snapshot-4 to zfshost2

```
[root@zfshost2~]# nc -w 120 -l -p 1234 | zfs receive -F -d zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f

[root@zfshost1~]# zfs send -F -R -I zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-1 zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-4 | nc -w zfshost2 1234
```

(How) does ZFS handle if we delete, during the process of sending the snapshots, snapshot-1, snapshot-2, snapshot-3 or snapshot-4

```
[root@zfshost1~]# zfs destroy zones/40e66d56-4ea8-11e5-885d-feff819cdc9f@snapshot-X
```

With X = 1, 2, 3, 4

Does ZFS handle this situation? What is the expected result on zfshost2?

Comment: That should be easy to test.

Comment: During a send I guess the snapshot is mounted, and hence you won't be able to remove... You can easily test this on a newly created volume.